# Spring Batch - how to launch job with file name received from rest API request

Tags: java, excel, spring, rest, spring-batch

I am trying to expose a Rest API and use it to receive a file name parameter and launch a Spring Batch job with it.

I want each request to launch the job and want my ItemReader to look for that file name.

I've read some other questions regarding how to launch a job via Rest API, and how the ItemReader can access jobParameters, but could not find a way to receive the parameters from the API request.
Below is my code:

```java
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private static final String WILL_BE_INJECTED = null;

    @Bean
    public Job processJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJobName")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Foo, Foo> chunk(1)
                .reader(excelReader(WILL_BE_INJECTED))
                .processor(new Processor()).faultTolerant().skipPolicy(skip())
                .writer(new Writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    ItemReader<Foo> excelReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) {
        PoiItemReader<Foo> reader = new PoiItemReader<>();
        reader.setLinesToSkip(3);
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("data/" + fileName));
        reader.setRowMapper(excelRowMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    private RowMapper<Foo> excelRowMapper() {
        return new FooExcelRowMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public SkipPolicy skip() {
        return new SkipPolicies();
    }

}
```

And my Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class BatchResource {

    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    private final Job job;

    public BatchResource(JobLauncher jobLauncher, Job job) {
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        this.job = job;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void launchJob(@RequestParam(value = "file_name", required = true) final String fileName) throws Exception {
        final JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        jobParametersBuilder.addString("fileName", fileName);

        final JobParameters jobParameters = jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters();

        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the ItemReader is understanding the fileName to be read. The job runs "successfully" but does not actually read my input file.

Edit: I started a new project with the same intention and noticed that as soon as I use the `@StepScope` annotation, it stops working and does not work again, even if I remove the `@StepScope` annotation. Now I'm trying to figure out how to overcome this

Comment: Your config LGTM. You just need to make sure that the value of the file name you get from the API is either relative to the classpath or an absolute path and use the correct `Resource` implementation accordingly (`ClassPathResource` or `FileSystemResource`).

Comment: Actually, if I do not use the parameters received by REST API, and use a hard-coded file name, it works. So I believe this is not a matter of using the correct Resource implementation.

Comment: In that case make sure that the resolved value coming from the rest call has the same base path as the value you hard coded.

Comment: I started a new project with the same intention and noticed that as soon as I use the `@StepScope` annotation, it stops working and does not work again, even if I remove the `@StepScope` annotation. Now I'm trying to figure out how to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, I noticed the ItemReader implementation I'm using to read excel files (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel) could not read the excel file as soon as I start using `@StepScope` annotation.

So I found this question [PoiItemReader with StepScope Annotation do not read Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092526/poiitemreader-with-stepscope-annotation-do-not-read-excel-file) answered by Niraj Sonawane.

Basically I had to change the return type from `ItemReader<Foo>` to `PoiItemReader<Foo>` below:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
PoiItemReader<Foo> excelReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) {
    PoiItemReader<Foo> reader = new PoiItemReader<>();
    reader.setLinesToSkip(3);
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("data/" + fileName));
    reader.setRowMapper(excelRowMapper());
    return reader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have exactly the same way of passing dynamically the path instead of the filename to the job:

```
reader.setResource(new PathResource(path));
```

Everything is working fine this way. Maybe try this.

+remember that Classpath resources must reside inside the jar. Where is your file located?

Comment: Same behavior. In the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION table, the EXIT_MESSAGE says: All steps already completed or no steps configured for this job.

My file is located inside src/main/resources/data. It works when I remove the jobParameters and use a hard coded file name.

Comment: The Job you injecting into BatchResource is for sure the job you configured in BatchConfig? Lookin into my code I have @Qualifier(#jobName) for my job @Bean and injection.

Comment: /+ jobParametersBuilder.addString("runId", <different_from_previous_one>) - Make sure that runId differs when running the job

Comment: Yes I am sure that I am running the same job declared in the BatchConfig class